# Use the data from the event listener withing the function of the Event Dispatcher

Tags: symfony, event-listener

Background: 
I would like to use the data from the event listener from the functions that called the event dispatcher. From what I can see the event dispatcher does only returns the GenericEvent object.

The main bundle is where the dispatcher is being called.

MainBundleController.php

```
public function mainBundle() {
 $this->getContainer()->get('event_dispatcher')->addListener('my_test_event', new GenericEvent($object))
// Is it possible to use the data from $anotherBundleListener

}
```

AnotherBundle/services.yml

```
another_bundle.listener:
  class:   ..../AnotherBundleEventService
  tags:
    - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: my_test_event, method: anotherBundleListener}
```

AnotherBundleEventService.php

```
public function anotherBundleListener(GenericEvent $event) {
 //Do amazing things
 return $somethingAmazing
}
```

The event listener and dispatcher works the only issue is I would like to use the data from the listener within the functions that called the dispatcher.

If there is another way of doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/event_dispatcher/method_behavior.html

```
 public function mainBundle() {

 $myEvent = MyEvent();
 $this->getContainer()->get('event_dispatcher')->addListener('my_test_event', $myEvent)
 $data = $myEvent->getData;

}
```